# How to filter a json list based on a predefined list

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I need some help to figure out how to achieve the following:

Following is the code:

```
public class Data
{
 public string FirstName;
 public string LastName;
 public int Age;
}

var data=new Data
{

 //this object is filled from the data i retreive from a database.

}).ToList();

var object = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
return object.
```

Upto this i can populate the data to my UI with the info i have in the "object".

Now i need to filter few members of the object and return only those to my UI.In order to do that i have a mapping xml file which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <FirstName return="True"/>
  <LastName return="False"/>
  <Age  return="True"/>
</Items>
```

**I query the xml file and form a list of what needs to be filtered and based on this xmllist i want to filter the "object" mentioned above and pass the data to the UI.**

Need some help how to achieve the above.

Comment: Are you trying to do this filtering in JavaScript or C#?

Comment: I am trying to do it in c#.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this in C# it looks like it's been covered here: 
[How to create a dynamic LINQ select projection function from a string[] of names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413290/how-to-create-a-dynamic-linq-select-projection-function-from-a-string-of-names)

I can't think of a way around the reflection.

Comment: I am looking more of filtering a list based of another list in c#.